# Why does split() return one extra item?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

I have this String and I want to separate it using the specified separator. Why is the length 4 instead of 3?

```
brain = " Know yourself! Understand yourself! Correct yourself! "
brain = brain.strip()
change = brain.split("yourself!")
print(len(change))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your word that you want to split with that (yourself!) is at the end(or at the first) of your string.

you can try this solution :

```
def is_not_none(element):
    if element is not None:
        return element


brain = "know yourself! Understand yourself! Correct yourself!  "
brain = brain.strip()
brain = list(filter(is_not_none, brain.rsplit('yourself!')))
print(brain)
```